# Is it possible to wrap text around a block element like a div in the same way you would an image

Tags: html, css

I know with images I can apply hspace, vspace, and/or align to make it go to one side or another with text flowing around it, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do something similar with an element like a div? If it is possible, how would one do that and comply with standards?

Comment: Like `style="float:left"` or `style="float:right"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it worked http://jsfiddle.net/q5swZ/1/

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid 1px red;
float:left; margin:0 10px">
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer 
quis lorem dui. Aliquam ut arcu eros. Etiam viverra rhoncus     
laoreet. Ut vel quam neque, sed rutrum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla orci est, tincidunt 
id pulvinar eget, ultrices non purus. Nullam tempor posuere sem, 
quis porttitor neque eleifend quis.


<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br />

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid 1px red;
float:left; margin:0 10px">
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer 
quis lorem dui. Aliquam ut arcu eros. Etiam viverra rhoncus 
laoreet. Ut vel quam neque, sed rutrum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla orci est, tincidunt 
id pulvinar eget, ultrices non purus. Nullam tempor posuere sem, 
quis porttitor neque eleifend quis.
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple css float property would do it or am I missing something